# After active directory settings where will be the registry key created

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'am using active directory to create a user, in an application,after that where will be the register key created in registry editor.

Comment: Several things: First, this does not seem to be a *programming* question per-se. Second, it is not entirely clear what you are asking  -- creating a user in Active Directory has next to nothing to do with creating a key in the registry on a local machine. If you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish, this may be a good fit for [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I want to know where the registry key would be crreated in local machine after active directory